# Installing ruby sudo make command not found (Vagrant, Virtualbox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to get a development environment up and running.  I installed virtualbox and then used vagrant with the hashicorp/precise32 box.  I access the VM through ssh and am trying to install the latest version of ruby.

I pasted

```
wget -O ruby-install-0.5.0.tar.gz https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/archive/v0.5.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-install-0.5.0.tar.gz
cd ruby-install-0.5.0/
sudo make install
```

into the command line from https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install#readme

The prompt shows sudo make install and when I hit enter I get a message that says "sudo: make: command not found."

What am I doing wrong?

I know there are boxes with ruby already setup but I wanted to go through the process myself so learn a bit along the way.

A separate issue I came across was that this box has an outdated version of ubuntu.  When I try to upgrade it warns me not to do it over SSH.  Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have **make** installed on Ubuntu. You can install the package **build-essential** which will install **make** and other building tools.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

also, [here's a good reference](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10) on installing Ruby, Ruby on Rails, and other tools on Ubuntu.